# how to pass multiple parameters in the url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

how to pass multiple parameters from view to the controller in the url.This is my url,and options.parentId is one parameter.I need to pass multiple values ,how can i pass multiple values from view to controller in the url.
("/ProjectRoles/project_module_functions_leftdisplay", options.parentid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Url.Action helper:

```
@Url.Action("project_module_functions_leftdisplay", "ProjectRoles", new 
{ 
    parentid = options.parentid, 
    somethingelse = options.somethingelse 
})
```

or if you are calling the controller within an action link:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "click me", 
    "project_module_functions_leftdisplay", 
    "ProjectRoles", 
    new { 
        parentid = options.parentid, 
        somethingelse = options.somethingelse 
    }, 
    null
)
```

or if you are using an HTML `<form>`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("project_module_functions_leftdisplay", "ProjectRoles", new { parentid = options.parentid, somethingelse = options.somethingelse }))
{
    ...
}
```

or if I misunderstood your question and `options` is a javascript variable::

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var options = ...
    var url = '@Url.Action("project_module_functions_leftdisplay", "ProjectRoles", new { parentid = "__parentid__", somethingelse = "__somethingelse__" })';
    url = url
        .replace('__parentid__', encodeURIComponent(options.parentid))
        .replace('__somethingelse__', encodeURIComponent(options.somethingelse));

    // ... use the url here
</script>
```

There might as well be other, better approaches depending on your exact scenario and what you are trying to achieve.